# I doing setTimeout loaing symbol in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Javascript setTimeout working well. but opacity starting in 1 to 0.5. How to fixed opacity 0.50 in setTimeout mode?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById('load').style.width = '100' + '%';
  document.getElementById('load').style.height = '100' + '%';
  document.getElementById('load').style.position = 'initial';
  document.getElementById('load').style.backgroundImage = "url('image/load.gif')";

  jQuery('#load').fadeOut(3000);
});
```

```css
#load {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.50 !important;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='load'>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Explain it clearly.

Comment: The context of what you are trying to ask is not clear.

Comment: try `.animate()` function (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below. Try using `animate`

```
var x = document.getElementById('load');
$(x).animate({opacity:0.5},3000);
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: I declare opacity 0.50 default. but timeout mode starts on opacity 1 hereafter reduce automatically finally opacity 0.5 set. how to fix opacity 0.50 fixed and visible background

Comment: It means that you are trying to make it fixed opacity after fading.?@karthick1870

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can do it like following way:

HTML, CSS and JS

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#load').removeClass('active');
  }, 1000)
});
```

```css
#load {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#load.active {
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='load' class="active">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif">
</div>
```

[Here is jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/emgeqa6h/6/)